# PrimeNG MenuCallback

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using p-panelmenu from the excellent prime-ng library.

```
<p-panelMenu [model]="items" (click)="onClicked(event)"></p-panelMenu>
```

Trouble is I can't work out how to get the menu to do anything.  The examples on the primeNG website all display menus but don't trigger any actions on them.

How can I get the currently selected item?  I note that there is a "command" callback on the menuItem class; but it seems crazy to define a callback for every menu item.  Rather than just one callback that gets passed the selected menu item.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I had to write a recursive function to loop through the menu-items and sub-items and assign a command callback to each one:

```
export class TreeViewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() onSelectedChanged: EventEmitter<MenuItem> = new EventEmitter<MenuItem>();

  items : any[] = [];

  constructor (private contentService: ContentService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.getFolders();
  }

  getFolders() {
    this.contentService.getFolders().subscribe(this.setItems);
  }

  setItems = (x: any) => {
      this.assignCallback(x);
      this.items = x.items;
  }

  assignCallback(item:MenuItem){
    if(item.items != null && item.items.length > 0) {
      item.items.forEach(x => this.assignCallback(x))
    }
    item.command = this.commandCallback;
  }

  commandCallback(ev){
    console.log(ev.item);
  }
}
```

I will leave the question open; there's got to be a better way?

Comment: This is in line with what I have done. Had different menus, with different methods to invoke and others were 'routerLinks'; so crating a loop for the items and for each item building the respective properties. However, there is an id property for each menu which one can set and pass it as an argument to the callback. Alternatively (theoretically as I haven't tested), the callback method has an event argument which I suppose should have the element that raised the event. e.g. `command: (event) => { //event should contain the element clicked.
        methodName()
      }`

Answer (score 0):

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/menumodel

You might want to read the documentation on MenuItem type for most of PrimeNG's Menu components. Inside the list of options an item might have, there's a 'command' option which executes a callback.